# Caesar Cipher C program not working

Tags: c, encryption

I have a caesar cipher program that I'm working on, and it involves replacing each letter in a message with another letter that is a fixed number of positions later in the alphabet. Also, it ignores numbers and spaces. However, no matter what I try, the program terminates instantly. Here is what I have so far;

```
#include <stdio.h>

char encrypt(char in, int key)
{
    while(in != '\n')
{
    if(in >= 'A' && in <= 'Z')
    {
        ((in-'A') + key) % 26 + 'A';
        printf("%s", in);
    }
        else if(in >= 'a' && in <= 'z')
    {
        ((in-'a') + key) % 26 + 'a';
        printf("%s", in);
    }
}
return 0;
}

int main()
{
int key;
String phrase;
char ch;

printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
scanf("%d ", &key);

printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
scanf(
encrypt(in, key);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(in != '\n')` : Infinite loop in except a newline

Comment: @Jordan Look at line `scanf(`.  Where is the rest of it?

Comment: Your program doesn't even compile. And you should indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues.

The main problem is, you are mixing up the encryption of a char and the encryption of a phrase. You should break down the problem into several sub-problems.

- problem 1: encrypting one single char
- problem 2: encrypting a phrase, which consists of encrypring every char of that phrase:

Working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char encryptchar(char in, int key)
{
  if (in >= 'A' && in <= 'Z')
  {
      in = ((in-'A') + key) % 26 + 'A';
  }
  else if(in >= 'a' && in <= 'z')
  {
      in = ((in-'a') + key) % 26 + 'a';
  }

  return in;
}


void encryptphrase(char phrase[], int key)
{
  int i = 0;
  char c ;
  while (c = phrase[i])
  {
    c = encryptchar(c, key);
    phrase[i] = c;
    i++;
  }
}


int main()
{
  int key;
  char phrase[100];

  printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
  scanf("%d", &key);

  printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
  scanf("%s", phrase);
  encryptphrase(phrase, key);
  printf("%s\n", phrase);
  return 0;
}
```